# hyperplane equation in SVM

Tags: vector, machine-learning, svm

How does the SVM algorithm find the optimum hyperplane? The positive margin hyperplane equation is **w**.**x**-b=1, the negative margin hyperplane equation is **w**.**x**-b=-1, and the middle(optimum) hyperplane equation is **w**.**x**-b=0).
I understand how a hyperplane equation can be got by using a normal vector of that plane and a known vector point(not the whole vector) by [this tutorial](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/dot-cross-products/v/defining-a-plane-in-r3-with-a-point-and-normal-vector). Lets say the known vector point is **x1**, the whole vector will be (**x**-**x1**), for some **x**. If **w** is the normal vector of the plane, then **w**.(**x**-**x1**)=0; eventually we will get the form **w**.**x**=b

Now, for getting a hyperplane, we need a normal vector and known point. How does the algorithm create a hyperplane at the middle where there is no data point (which I think is a known vector point needed in the equation) from training data?

Maybe I misunderstand something or my logic is not correct.

Comment: Do *you* want to have the hyperplane equation, or are you just wondering how the SVM routines work with that hyperplane?

Comment: i am wondering, with training data how svm create a hyperplane(because svm need that hyperplane to take decision for testing data later whether it is positive or negative)

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand one basic fact: the algorithm is not required to represent a hyperplane in terms of **w.x-b = 0**, using a given data point.  The algorithm is free to change this into any form convenient to each of its functions.

The solution is obvious, as you've already found it: the algorithm does *not* have to use one of the points form the data set.  In fact, if the partition is ideal (no data on the wrong side), there *is* no point in the middle.

However, finding that hyperplane is trivial.  (1) The positive and negative hyperplanes are parallel, and (2) the optimum plane bisects their separation.  By (1), all three planes have the same normal vector.  By (2), the reference point can be the midpoint of any segment connecting two points on opposite planes.

Briefly, pick a positive support vector and a negative support vector; these lie one on each of the planes.  Find the midpoint between them, convolve with the normal vector, and there's your optimum plane.

Comment: I am not clear about your points in first 2 para of your answer, are you mean kernel by "function"? one thing i understand the algorithm do not get the optimal hyperplane first , so, is it make the positive and negative hyperplane(most farthest to each other) first by the support vectors? if so, how the 1 of w.x-b=1 comes from? i guess, I am again making the understanding miserable, sorry for that.

Comment: By "function", I intend the common meaning of the term: any individual bit of work the algorithm does.  The order of finding the hyperplanes is up to the algorithm.

Comment: For your other question, from where do we get the **1** of **w.x-b=1** ... this is a consequence of normalizing the vector computations.  The derivation is beyond the scope of SO.  If your first tutorial didn't explain it well enough, try [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_DJ4KvyYoo).